# A 30 page tcpdf pdf document won't open in Fancybox 2 using Chrome/IE

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox, tcpdf, fancybox-2

I am trying to open a 30 page PDF document in Fancybox 2, the PDF document is generated using TCPDF and then needs to display on screen so the user can print or save it. When the script finishes the fancybox loading graphic shows for eternity and no iframe opens. It has worked in Firefox but not in Chrome or IE.

If i reduce the number of pages to 23 it opens, i have also tried creating the pdf first and saving to the server and then opening it using the below javascript.

delivery_pdf.php is the script for creating the TCPDF which then saves it as delivery2.pdf

```
$.get('delivery_pdf.php',
{
    type:0,
    this_id:new_tick,
    delivery_run_date:dd
},function(data)
{
    $.fancybox.open(
    {
        type: 'iframe',
        href: 'delivery2.pdf'
    });
    $("#loader").hide();

});
```

The PDF has been created as by putting the link directly in the browser bar opens the file.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It has been reported this type of behavior with Chrome and IE and the quickest workaround is to disable the fancybox's `iframe` `preload` so try  :

```
$.get('delivery_pdf.php', {
    type: 0,
    this_id: new_tick,
    delivery_run_date: dd
}, function (data) {
    $.fancybox.open({
        type: 'iframe',
        href: 'delivery2.pdf',
        iframe: {
            preload: false
        }
    });
    $("#loader").hide();
});
```

You can also check the reported issue and workaround here https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/579 for further reference.

Comment: Thanks for that, that solves the fancybox issue! Now it appears TCPDF has an issue with multiple pages, as it just returns one page when i try and create anymore than 28 pages??

Comment: @Sherwood : maybe `delivery2.pdf` isn't completely done when is rendered in fancybox. You may need to check your `get` function (use ajax and render the document until `success`. Does `data` actually returns the PDF? so you could do `$.fancybox(data,{//options})`

Comment: The pdf is created depending on the number of delivery notes selected by the user, if i select 28 it renders fine, for 29 or 30 it just gives up! the page TCPDF returns has a blank body with the pre-designed Header and Footer, if i run the php script without the TCPDF convert the HTML creates fine without any errors which i know can stop TCPDF rendering the page.